# Real-valued measurability vs. Two-valued measurability in determining whether $CH$ holds or not

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

The following fact is known:

> If there is a measurable cardinal, then there are only countably many constructible reals.

It is also known that if $ZFC$ + "There is a (two-valued) mesurable cardinal" is consistent, then $ZFC$ + "There exists a (two-valued) measurable cardinal" + $CH$ is also consistent.

If one replaces "There exists a (two-valued) measurable cardinal" with "The cardinality of the continuum is a real-valued measurable cardinal", is

i)$ZFC$ + "The cardinality of the continuum is a real-valued measurable cardinal" + $CH$ is consistent if $ZFC$ + "The cardinality of the continuum is a real-valued measurable cardinal" is consistent (it is not, by a result of Banach and Kuratowski)? Also,

ii) Does $ZFC$ + "The cardinality of the continuum is a real-valued measurable cardinal" imply that there are only countably many constructible reals?

Since i) is inconsistent, how is it possible that $ZFC$ + "The cardinality of the continuum is a real-valued measurable" implies $\lnot$$CH$ while $ZFC$+ "There exists a (two-valued) measurable cardinal" is consistent with $CH$ or $\lnot$$CH$?

Comment: Yes, much weaker assumptions (consistencywise) imply that $\mathbb R\cap L$ is countable. On the other hand, any (atomless) real-valued measurable cardinal has size at most the continuum. Any such cardinal is weakly inaccessible (and much more), so $\mathsf{CH}$ fails badly under such an assumption. I suggest you study some basic model theory (completeness and compactness for first-order logic, for instance), even before studying axiomatic set theory, because your questions have been revealing serious gaps regarding basic concepts (in this case, consistency is not the same as provability).

Comment: How is it possible that *ZFC* + "$2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$" implies $\neg CH$ while *ZFC* is consistent with *CH* since the two theories are equiconsistent?

Comment: Re: your edited last paragraph, like I say in my answer there's no tension here: "the continuum is real-valued measurable" and "there is a measurable cardinal" are very different principles, there's no reason to *expect* them to have the same consequences for cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  and yet a two-valued measurable cardinal $\kappa$ can become real-valued measurable in a forcing extension (and $\kappa$=$2^{\aleph_0}$ in that same forcing extension--Theorem 22.1(ii) in Jech 2003) , and the real-valued measurable cardinal $\kappa$ in the forcing extension can be a two-valued measurable cardinal in an inner model of that same forcing extension. You yourself said that " a cardinal is measurable iff it is real-valued measurable (to quote Jech's Corollary 10.15:  "Every real-valued measurable cardinal is weakly inaccesible") and strongly inaccessible".

Comment: (cont.) How different can these principles be (and in what sense can these principles be different) if one prove a theorem like Theorem 22.1(i, ii) (and one of course can....)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin "the real-valued measurable cardinal $\kappa$ in the forcing extension can be a two-valued measurable cardinal **in an inner model of that same forcing extension**." Yes, $\kappa$ is inaccessible **in that inner model**, but not in the whole forcing extension. Which is why $\kappa$ is measurable **in the inner model**, but merely real-valued measurable in the whole forcing extension. There is no tension here at all.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Correct. No tension at all but regarding that inner model (where $\kappa$ is two-valued measurable), can one construct forcing extensions of that inner model where $CH$, $\lnot$$CH$ hold respectively and $\kappa$ remains two-valued measurable?  What has to happen for that to occur (if in fact it does happen)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin "can one construct forcing extensions of that inner model where CH, $\neg$CH hold respectively and $\kappa$ remains two-valued measurable?" Yes, and this has nothing to do with the inner model in question: measurability (unlike real-valued measurability) is "preserved by small forcing," i.e. if $\kappa$ is measurable then it stays measurable in any forcing extension by a forcing of cardinality $<\kappa$ (this is due to Levy and Solovay). Since CH and $\neg$CH can each be forced with small forcings, this means that we can always control CH while preserving a measurable.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin You ask "How different can these principles be" - well, there's no precise definition of that, but the following facts paint a pretty complete picture: the measurables are exactly the inaccessible real-valued measurables, while real-valued measurables can be "small" (e.g. size continuum). That said, particular values being real-valued measurable can have arithmetic implications - namely, if the continuum is real-valued measurable then CH fails - while this is moot for actual measurables (since they can't be small). If this isn't satisfying, I'll need more specific questions.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Regarding real-valued measurables becoming 'small', Cantor's attic (upper attic) says of weakly inaccessible cardinals,"...but forcing arguments show that any [strongly?] inaccessible cardinal can become a non-inaccessible weakly inaccessible cardinal in a forcing extension, such as after adding an enormous number of Cohen reals ..." (e.g. Jech-Solovay's Theorem 22.1(ii) from Jech, _Set Theory_ (2003), pg. 410). What "enormous number" would that be, exactly (it couldn't be a class-size forcing, because that would negate the Powerset axiom....)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin If you add $\kappa$-many reals, then $\kappa\le2^{\aleph_0}$, so that will kill strong inaccessibility. *Weak* inaccessibility, though, can't be killed just by adding "enough reals:" forcing with finite partial maps from $\lambda\times\omega$ to $2$ adds $\lambda$-many reals but is c.c.c., so preserves cardinals and cofinalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it is **not** the case that if ZFC is consistent, then ZFC + CH + "There is a measurable" is consistent; a measurable cardinal has *much* greater consistency strength than ZFC alone. What **is** true is that if ZFC + "There is a measurable" is consistent, then so is ZFC + CH + "There is a measurable;" I think this is what you mean.

*A bit of clarification, just to pin things down: when we say "If $A$ is consistent, then $B$ is consistent," this is usually shorthand for "$T$ proves $Con(A)\implies Con(B)$" where $T$ is some reasonable weak theory (PRA is almost always enough); such an interpretation is needed to avoid stupidity (if ZFC is consistent, then the sentence "PA is consistent implies ZFC is consistent" is technically true, even though what we **mean** by it clearly isn't). So, elaborating a bit on the previous paragraph, here are a couple things PRA proves:*

- *"If ZFC + "There is a measurable" is consistent, then ZFC + CH + "There is a measurable" is consistent."*
- *"If PRA proves "If ZFC is consistent, then ZFC + "There is a measurable cardinal" is consistent," then ZFC is inconsistent."*

*No, that second one wasn't a typo.*

---

Now re: question 1, you ask:

> how is it possible that ZFC + "The cardinality of the continuum is a real-valued measurable" implies $\neg$CH while ZFC+ "There exists a (two-valued) measurable cardinal" is consistent with CH since the two theories are equiconsistent?

There's no tension here - equiconsistent theories can disagree. Equiconsistency doesn't mean that they're consistent *together*, but rather that each is consistent if and only if the other is consistent. For example, ZFC+CH and ZFC+$\neg$CH are equiconsistent, but clearly inconsistent with each other.

So there's no issue.

---

Re: question 2, off the top of my head I'm not sure, but if memory serves Solovay showed that if there is a real-valued measurable, then there is an inner model with a measurable *(it is certainly true that he showed that "there is a real-valued measurable" and "there is a measurable" are equiconsistent over ZFC; but it's possible he build an inner model of a forcing extension, instead of an actual inner model, which would be a problem here)*. If my memory is correct, then the answer to 2 is "yes:" letting $M$ be that inner model, we have $M\models \vert\mathbb{R}^L\vert=\aleph_0$. But $L$ (hence $\mathbb{R}^L$) and $\aleph_0$ are absolute, so $V\models\vert\mathbb{R}^L\vert=\aleph_0$.

*Note that this is stronger than what you ask for in (2): the conclusion is that if there is a real-valued measurable **at all**, regardless of its comparison with the continuum, then $\mathbb{R}^L$ is countable.*

Comment: Re your first paragraph. Well, yes, it *is* the case. But it is not provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. :-) (Thomas, this comment is sort-of an inside joke, I am not actually contradicting anything Noah wrote.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo No, no, it *is* provable in ZFC since ZFC is clearly inconsistent :P.

Comment: For question 2, your recollection of what Solovay proved is correct: If there is a real-vaued measurable cardinal $\kappa$, then in an inner model $\kappa$ is genuinely measurable. So $0^\sharp$ exists, which is more than an overkill to see that $\mathbb R\cap L$ is countable.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Sweet, I *was* paying attention! Is there an easier way to get countability of $\mathbb{R}^L$ from a real-valued measurable than this?

Comment: It seems to be the fastest argument: If $I$ is the witnessing ideal, then $\kappa$ is measurable in $L[I]$. I of course like to argue instead as in [my paper](https://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/crm-rvm.pdf): If $\kappa$ is real-valued measurable, then there is a generic embedding of the universe into a transitive model, which in particular gives us $0^\sharp$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Since by one version of G$\ddot o$del's completeness theorem ("A (first-order) theory $T$ is consistent iff it has a model"), equiconsistency merely states that two first-order theories $T_{\alpha}$ and $T_{\beta}$ are equiconsistent iff each proves the other has a model, correct?  And equiconsistency is an equivalence relation on first-order theories $T_{\alpha}$, $T_{\beta}$ (correct also)?

Comment: @Thomas No, that is not a correct restatement, because of the incompleteness theorem (among other reasons). (And yes, equiconsistency is an equivalence relation.)

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin That's not what equiconsistency means; $T_1$ and $T_2$ are equiconsistent if PRA (say) proves "$Con(T_1)\iff Con(T_2)$," not if $T_1$ proves $Con(T_2)$ and vice versa. (In fact, we can *never* have them prove each others' consistency if they're reasonable theories - see [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2076825/28111).) Completeness says that we can replace "is consistent" with "has a model," of course, but I don't see how that's relevant here. Regardless, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question you're asking here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Thanks for clearing up that misconception of mine.  I find the following comment of Andres intriguing:  "For question 2, your recollection of what Solovay proved is correct:  If there is a real-valued measurable cardinal $\kappa$, then in an inner model [of some forcing extension?--my comment] $\kappa$ is genuinely measurable".   Question:  If there is a two-valued measurable cardinal $\kappa$, then is there an inner model (of a forcing extension or otherwise) in which $\kappa$ is real-valued measurable?  Since the assumption of the existence of a real-valued measurable

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Measurable cardinals *are* real-valued measurable already. More precisely: if memory serves, a cardinal is measurable iff it is real-valued measurable and inaccessible (this should be in Jech's big book, but I don't have it on hand).

Comment: (cont.) cardinal implies $\lnot$$CH$, it seems reasonable (possibly) to (informally) infer that there is a submodel $\mathfrak N$ of $\mathfrak M$$\vDash$ $ZFC$ + "The cardinality of the continuum is a real-valued measurable cardinal"  in which $CH$ holds (and $\kappa$ is two-valued measurable)(I hope I have made no errors in what I wrote here).

Comment: An interesting question is whether, for $\kappa$ a measurable cardinal, there's a forcing which will kill the strong inaccessibility (when I said "inaccessible" above I meant "strongly inaccessible") of $\kappa$ (in particular, push the continuum above $\kappa$) but preserve the real-valued measurability of $\kappa$; I suspect the answer is yes, but I don't immediately see how to do it. @AndrésE.Caicedo Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  I agree.  That _is_ an interesting question!

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin "it seems reasonable (possibly) to (informally) infer that there is a [model satisfying] "The cardinality of the continuum is a real-valued measurable cardinal" in which CH holds." That can't happen - CH contradicts the real-valued measurability of the continuum.

Comment: @Noah Just add random reals.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Oh yeah, d'oy.

Comment: So basically, given a forcing extension $\mathfrak M$[$G$] of $L$ in which $\lnot$$CH$ holds, $L$ is not an inner model of $\mathfrak M$[$G$] (since $\mathfrak M$[$G$] $\vDash$ $ZFC$ + $\lnot$$CH$)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  So in Andres' comment to you, the inner model in which $\kappa$ becomes two-valued measurable also satisfies $\lnot$$CH$?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin No, $L$ (or rather, $L^M=L^{M[G]}$)  is an inner model of $M[G]$ - I don't know why you think it isn't. Whenever $N$ is a model of ZFC, $L^N$ is an inner model of $N$: it is a transitive (as far as $N$ is concerned) subclass of $N$ satisfying the ZFC axioms and containing all the ordinals in $N$. It's not generally an *elementary* substructure - if $N\not=L^N$, then $L^N\not\preccurlyeq N$ since $L^N\models V=L$ but $N\not\models V=L$ - but nobody said it had to be.

Comment: Re: your second comment, adding random reals preserves cardinalities - since $\kappa>\omega_1$ in $M$, it remains $>\omega_1$ in $M[G]$, and since $(2^{\aleph_0})^{M[G]}=\kappa$ we have $M[G]\models\neg CH$. But you **already know** it has to satisfy $\neg$CH, since ZFC + CH contradicts "the continuum is real-valued measurable" and we've made $\kappa$ be the continuum and stay real-valued measurable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Since the forcing extension $\mathfrak M$[$G$] of $L$ was constructed to satisfy $\lnot$$CH$, $\mathfrak M$[$G$] $\vDash$ $ZFC$ + $\lnot$$CH$, so though $L$ $\vDash$ $ZFC$ (or, like $HF$ $\vDash$ $ZFC$ + $\lnot$_Infinity_, $L$ $vDash$ $ZFC$ + $V$=$L$), $ZFC$ is a fragment of $ZFC$ + $\lnot$$CH$ (but since $L$ $\vDash$ $ZFC$ + $V$=$L$, $L$ in that sense cannot be a submodel of $\mathfrak M$[$G$] (but that interpretation would correspond to $L$ not being an elementary substructure of $\mathfrak M$[$G$], correct?).

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin $L$ **is** a submodel of $M[G]$. It's not an *elementary* submodel (since it satisfies $V=L$ but $M[G]$ doesn't), but that's different..